# Array of pointers, to shared objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an array list that carries an array of pointers to existing static objects.  Somehow, it manages to leak lots of memory.

```
Fruit fruits[20];
Fruit **list;

void addFruites()
{
    list = new Fruit*[10];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        list[i] = &fruits[i];
    }
}
```

Until now, everything seems to be working.  But whenever I want to delete (list):

```
 delete []list;
```

it seems to crash.

HELP!!

Comment: When you end up with `**` you are almost always doing something wrong, or trying too hard. You could just as well have `Fruit* list[10]` and skip the new and delete.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want to do

```
list = new Fruit * [10];
```

If `list` is supposed to be an array of `Fruit` pointers. The following:

```
list = new Fruit[10];
```

is allocating memory for 10 new `Fruit` objects using the default constructors rather than 10 pointers to `Fruit` objects.

Comment: Why allocate dynamically if you know you need 10 elements?

Comment: @Bo Persson I'm assuming @user686776 has a reason. I agree that just declaring `Fruit * list[10];` seems like a preferred method given the provided context.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the line

```
list = new Fruit[10];
```

is a typo, and that a `*` is missing.  Otherwise the code won't compile.
Assuming this, there's nothing wrong with the code you show here.
(Technically—one could definitely disagree with the design.)  The
problem is elsewhere, possibly a corruption of the free space arena.
(Try running the code under valgrind, and see what it tells you.)

Comment: I really apologize, I forgot to write (*).

Comment: Anyway, this is not what's wrong with the code. It still crashes.